# Legal / clean way to put UITableViewCell at the front of subview hierarchy?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UITableView` class that lays out the buttons for my menus like following:

[image]

As you can see, when a `UIButtons` highlight gets activated, the top part gets cut off by the `UITableViewCell` on top of it. Setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO` on the `UITableViewCell` property changes nothing since it's below the top view in the hierarchy.

Does anyone know if it's possible to remedy this situation without having to increase the size of the `UITableViewCell` so it can fit the `UIButton` highlight? Is it possible to reinsert the cell to the front of the `UITableViews` subviews when the button gets pushed without doing anything illegal?

Comment: Have you tried in `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` to try and bring the cell that is that button's type (do a conditional check for the class of button it is) and calling `tableView.bringSubviewToFront(myCustomButtonCell)` before returning?

Comment: @NSGangster that worked actually thanks! I put it in the selector for when the button is UIControlEventTouchDown, do you want to put it as the answer?